# What does two successive read operation mean for proxy_read_timeout in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I am checking the description of proxy_read_timeout from [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

```
Syntax : proxy_read_timeout time;
Default: proxy_read_timeout 60s;
Context: http, server, location
```

Defines a timeout for reading a response from the proxied server. **The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response.** If the proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.

What does the statement in bold actually means?

Comment: Did you make any sense out of this ?